# python loop to run for a second then wait for 1 minute and do it infinitely

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop, timer, timedelta

I'm fetching some stock market data every seconds and need to print volume for just one iteration or second and then explicitly wait for 60 seconds and then do it
infinitely.

For example if i start at 9:00 AM then using first  `tick['exchange_timestamp']` as start_time i'd like to iterate over time or timedelta package of python such that it should give me the volume from the stock data after a interval of 1 min means at 9:01 AM and then doing it infinitely.

The code is like this currently:

```
    def ROC(self,df,tick):
        global start_time 
        global timespan
        start_time = tick['exchange_timestamp']
        prev_volume = tick['volume_traded']
        timespan = start_time + timedelta(seconds = int(60))
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if start_time < timespan :
                prev_volume = tick['volume_traded']
```

This should run for just **one iteration** then it should **wait for a minute** and do it continuously for infinite until runtime.

Please anyone can help me by solving this using some loops over time and
datetime package of python.

And i'm running this code as a method inside a class so tried with multithreading and multiprocessing but it didn't helped me in any ways so please try to solve this issue only with time and datetime package of python.

Thanks. :)

Comment: What attempt have you made to use the time and datetime packages of Python?

Comment: you can use the `sleep` function to pause then continue https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep also, it would be more 'pythonic to write `while (1):` as `while True:`

Comment: Hey @nicomp here is the update code where i'm trying with datetime package of python to solve the issue but it's working as expected. If you've any soln for this can you please specify it here please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a <kbd>Generator Function</kbd> that will implement your own custom iteration logic. 
The next example illustrates an iteration logic of a 60-sec delay between iterations. 
This way, you can add future iteration logic to the same generator, while leaving the principal loop simple. As seen in the example below, I added a circular looping and a global stop flag as such enhancements.

**Example:**

```py
import time
import pandas as pd

demo_cnt = 0
data = {
  "tickers" : ['NASDAQ:GOOG','NASDAQ:AMZN','NASDAQ:MSFT','NASDAQ:AAPL', 'NASDAQ:META'],
  "values": [101.07, 112.62, 236.80, 141.62, 131.30]
}

# suggested generator function
def cyclic_dataframe_generator(df: pd.DataFrame):
    index = 0
    global cyclic_gen_stop
    cyclic_gen_stop = False
    while True:
        yield index, df.iloc[[index]]
        time.sleep(60)
        index += 1
        if index > df.shape[0] - 1:
            index = 0
        if cyclic_gen_stop:
            break

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# loop with custom iteration logic
for index, df_row in cyclic_dataframe_generator(df):
    print (f'index={index}\n{df_row}\n')
    demo_cnt += 1
    if demo_cnt >= 10:
        cyclic_gen_stop = True
```

**Output:**

```
index=0
       tickers  values
0  NASDAQ:GOOG  101.07

index=1
       tickers  values
1  NASDAQ:AMZN  112.62

index=2
       tickers  values
2  NASDAQ:MSFT   236.8

index=3
       tickers  values
3  NASDAQ:AAPL  141.62

index=4
       tickers  values
4  NASDAQ:META   131.3

index=0
       tickers  values
0  NASDAQ:GOOG  101.07

index=1
       tickers  values
1  NASDAQ:AMZN  112.62

index=2
       tickers  values
2  NASDAQ:MSFT   236.8

index=3
       tickers  values
3  NASDAQ:AAPL  141.62

index=4
       tickers  values
4  NASDAQ:META   131.3
```